# Remove zero width space unicode character from Python string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a string in Python like this:

```
u'\u200cHealth & Fitness'
```

How can i remove the

```
\u200c
```

part from the string ?

Comment: `s.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @Vinny the return string is `\xe2\x80\x8cHealth & Fitness`

Comment: my bad, the encoding should be `ascii` as Arount answered below

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can encode it into `ascii` and ignore errors:

```
u'\u200cHealth & Fitness'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Output:

```
'Health & Fitness'
```

Comment: This obviously works in the above example but you are forcing the string into ascii losing all unicode chars, which obviously is not a solution that works for all

Answer (score 32):

If you have a string that contains `Unicode` character, like

```
s = "Airports Council International \u2013 North America"
```

then you can try:

```
newString = (s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')).decode("utf-8")
```

and the output will be:

`Airports Council International  North America`

*Upvote if helps* :)

Comment: shouldn't we decode 'ascii' after encoding to ascii

Comment: If you have a list of strings, you can adapt this as a list comprehension: `list_text_fixed = [(s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')).decode("utf-8") for s in list_text]`

Answer (score 25):

I just use replace because I don't need it:

```
varstring.replace('\u200c', '')
```

Or in your case:

```
u'\u200cHealth & Fitness'.replace('\u200c', '')
```

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted answer in most strings. The \u200c is a zero width non joiner, which is an unusual whitespace-type character that `strip()` ignores. In most cases with unicode strs you do not want to `encode(ascii, ignore)`.

Comment: This is general solution since ascii may remove some other Unicode characters as well.

Comment: appreciate this!

Answer (score 5):

for me the following worked

```
mystring.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining _why_ this code works, and what you're doing here. That way, others can be educated.

Comment: tbh, that was a 'Frankenstein' version of all answers that I had previously found but which didn't work. I can't really explain why this one worked over the rest of solutions in my case..

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case in the question: that the string is prefixed with a single `u'\200c'` character, the solution is as simple as taking a slice that does not include the first character.

```py
original = u'\u200cHealth & Fitness'
fixed = original[1:]
```

If the leading character may or may not be present, [str.lstrip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) may be used

```py
original = u'\u200cHealth & Fitness'
fixed = original.lstrip(u'\u200c')
```

The same solutions will work in Python3.  From Python 3.9, [str.removeprefix](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) is also available

```py
original = u'\u200cHealth & Fitness'
fixed = original.removeprefix(u'\u200c')
```