# How to avoid unicode string in python3?

Tags: unicode, python-3.6

I have read a csv file in which there are many values which have been read as unicode. While doing my data processing, I want to skip these values.
Existing Code:

```
if aString.encode('ascii', 'ignore') == b'':
    continue
```

The same code is working when i am trying this in python environment. But it is not working in script(.py file).

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154561/remove-unicode-character-from-python-string  I saw an answer here.

Comment: Try to just print the string in both envs. Check the diferences. Try again printing the ord number of the character and check differences again. I assume there is some problem on your environment (are you sure that py files are excuted by python3?)

Comment: Show a reproducible example of your script.  Read and follow [mcve]