# Remove unicode characters from returned variable - Tautulli Newsletter

Tags: python, html, unicode, ascii, mako

I want to include actors from films in my Tautulli newsletter for my Plex media collection. The newsletter template file is html and the language is mako so a mix of python, html and css.

This code returns the correct values

```
<p style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 400;margin: 0;max-width: 325px;color: #ffffff;">

Actors: ${movie['actors']}

</p>
```

It appears like

```
Actors: [u'Amalia Williamson', u'Celina Martin', u'Joelle Farrow']
```

To be usable I'd need to remove the the unicode characters

```
 [u'
```

I have tried a couple of things and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154561/remove-unicode-character-from-python-string) was the most promising lead, however I couldn't get it to work.

Can anyone please amend the code so it will work please? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove unicode character from python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154561/remove-unicode-character-from-python-string)

Comment: Please edit the answer to show how exactly you want the output to look like.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings) is maybe relevant to your problem too.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. For the above example I wanted the output to be

Actors: Glynn Turman, Hailee Steinfeld, Jason

The answer given by snakecharmerb worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movie['actors']` appears to be a list, so rendering it will the repr of the list and its contents.  Joining the invidual strings into a lrager string should do what you want.

```
>>> print u', '.join([u'Amalia Williamson', u'Celina Martin', u'Joelle Farrow'])
Amalia Williamson, Celina Martin, Joelle Farrow
```

In your template:

```
Actors: ${u', '.join(movie['actors'])}
```