# Improve Data Preprocessing Speed - Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, emoji, python-re

I use the following class in Python to preprocess a string before passing it to a machine learning classification model for predicting its sentiment.

I use regex for most of the transformation along with some libraries like emoji and tweet-preprocessor. The code works fine but I believe that it is slow.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve its speed?

Example of usage:

```
string  = "I am very happy with @easyjet #happy customer . Second sentence"
preprocessor = TextPreprocessing()
result = preprocessor.text_preprocessor(string)
```

The result will be : ["i am very happy with happy smiling face", "second sentence", "i am very happy with happy smiling face second sentence"]

```
import re
import preprocessor as p   # this is the tweet-preprocessor library
import emoji
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class TextPreprocessing:
    def __init__(self):
        p.set_options(p.OPT.MENTION, p.OPT.URL)

    # remove punctuation
    def _punctuation(self, val):
        val = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', val)
        val = re.sub('_', ' ', val)
        return val

    #remove white spaces
    def _whitespace(self, val):
        return " ".join(val.split())

    #remove numbers
    def _removenumbers(self, val):
        val = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', val)
        return val

    #remove unicode
    def _remove_unicode(self, val):
        val = unidecode(val).encode("ascii")
        val = str(val, "ascii")
        return val

    #split string into sentenses
    def _split_to_sentences(self, body_text):
        sentences = re.split(
            r"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s", body_text)
        return sentences

    # cleaning functions that combines all of the above functions
    def _clean_text(self, val):
        val = val.lower()
        val = self._removenumbers(val)
        val = p.clean(val)
        val = ' '.join(self._punctuation(emoji.demojize(val)).split())
        val = self._remove_unicode(val)
        val = self._whitespace(val)
        return val

    def text_preprocessor(self, body_text):
        body_text_df = pd.DataFrame({"body_text": body_text}, index=[1])
        sentence_split_df = body_text_df.copy()
        sentence_split_df["body_text"] = sentence_split_df["body_text"].apply(
            self._split_to_sentences)

        lst_col = "body_text"
        sentence_split_df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                col: np.repeat(
                    sentence_split_df[col].values, sentence_split_df[lst_col].str.len(
                    )
                )
                for col in sentence_split_df.columns.drop(lst_col)
            }
        ).assign(**{lst_col: np.concatenate(sentence_split_df[lst_col].values)})[
            sentence_split_df.columns
        ]

        final_df = (
            pd.concat([sentence_split_df, body_text_df])
            .reset_index()
            .drop(columns=["index"])
        )

        final_df["body_text"] = final_df["body_text"].apply(self._clean_text)

        return final_df["body_text"]
```

This question might be relevant to all those Data Scientists who want to move their NLP models into production.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I cannot comment I will try to answer your question (to some extent):

1. You should clarify how to measure the execution time improvement. Use timeit and its repeat functionality for that:

```
import timeit
from functools import partial
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # http://25.io/toau/audio/sample.txt
    with open("sample.txt") as f:
        text = f.read()
        tp = TextPreprocessing()
        print(min(timeit.Timer(partial(tp.text_preprocessor, text)).repeat(repeat=10, number=1)))
```

You can also use timeit on specific methdos to check for bottlenecks.

2. Sadly I could not run your code sample due to the undefined `np.` in L58 and L64
   so I cannot test my assumptions. Also you did not provide sample data.
3. Some general thoughts:

- Use `re.compile()` to compile all of your regular expressions
- If you do not need the modularity of _remove* you might consider combining these regular expressions
- `.copy()` operations are expensive try to get rid of them
- Also some of the _remove* methods have a smell. See the links for alternatives:

  - [Remove zero width space unicode character from Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154561/remove-zero-width-space-unicode-character-from-python-string)
  - [Removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851791/removing-numbers-from-string)

Comment: I have updated my code to include np and included an example. Could you give an example of the compile?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects

Comment: I am happy to accept your answer if you add few more details e.g. in which code smell are you referring to? An example of the compile using my code would be nice.

Comment: Okay if the link to the documentation is not enough:
```pattern = re.compile(r"_")
    pattern.sub("", "asdf_asdf")```

Comment: I thought the code smells where covered by the links posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222964/discussion-between-stamatis-tiniakos-and-philippselenium).